# problems with gradle version syncing

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

```
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ApplicationExtensionImpl$AgpDecorated.
      > Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.LintImpl$AgpDecorated.
         > Could not generate a decorated class for type LintImpl$AgpDecorated.
            > com/android/tools/lint/model/LintModelSeverity has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.InvalidPluginException: An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.exceptionOccurred(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:222)
    at ... 268 more
```

I've been trying to run my android project on my school computer but I'm almost certain it's a different version of android then mine and I can't update it is there any way I can downgrade my project so it runs on this computer?

Comment: if you want to downgrade your gradle then you need to make changes in ```build.gradle(project-level)``` and change gradle version here